# how do I loop through, line by line, the contexts from a textarea in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, streaming

how do I loop through, line by line, the contexts from a textarea in asp.net?

streamreader and stream both don't accept a string.

Comment: There's always a `System.IO.StringReader`.  But this is just a comment because to actually answer you I need to know more about at how you've defined the textarea.

Comment: foreach (string str in myString.split('\n')) {...}?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to split the text in the `TextBox` control into lines yourself:

```
var textLines = myTextbox.Text.Split('\n');
foreach( var line in textLines )
   // your code...
```

Comment: +1 - This is what I want thinking, but it seemed like some trick question to me so I just put it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to split the TextBox Text into your array and loop through it

```
txtArea.Text.Split('\n');
```

in .Net 3.5 or above

```
 var s = txtArea.Text.Split('\n');

 Array.ForEach(s, r => YourLoop(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use foreach loop on following array-

```
string[] lines = TextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Check [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1466576.aspx?For%20Each%20Line%20in%20textbox)

I hope this will help.